# jquery flip between val() or text() based on if the page is editable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out if there is already a function to do the following or how would I write a new one
if the page is editable, i build a table with text boxes in it.

```
<td><input type="text" id="blah" ... > </td>
```

otherwide:

```
<td id="blah">Sometext</td>
```

and then I build another table based on values from this table.

To get the value of the input box in jquery
i do:

```
$('#blah').val()
```

otherwise

```
$('#blah').text()
```

I want to write a function that based on the flag (isEditable) return the elements .val or .text
for example

```
jquery.fn.getValue = function() {
    if (isEditable){
        return $(this).val()
    }
    else {
        return $(this).text()
    }
 }
```

and then I would be able to do:

```
$('#blah').getValue()
```

and I wouldn't care whether its a cell or input box

Comment: was there a question somewhere there? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were basically already there:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getValue = function() {
        switch(this.get(0).nodeName) {
            case"INPUT": return this.val();
            break;
            default: return this.text(); 
            break;
        }
     }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

`isEditable` should be `$(this).is('input[type=text]')`

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `this.tagName` to see if the element is an input or a td and return the value or the text according to that